# Django 'str' object is not callable and subuser register

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Im try different method for user register. I want to enroll a company staff user: I want to register method "companyname.staffusername" but I cant do register. How can I do it? Im try different way but I have error.

I seen this error: "'str' object is not callable"

Forms:

```
     from django import forms


from django.db.models import fields
from .models import SubUser

class SubUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SubUser
        fields = ["Subusername","Subpassword","active","staff","Company"]
```

Views:

```
     from article.views import index
from user.views import loginUser
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from . import forms
from .models import SubUser
# Create your views here.
def RegisterSubUser(request):

    if request.method=="POST":

        form = forms.SubUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get("Subusername")
            password = form.cleaned_data.get("Subpassword")
            newUser = SubUser(Subusername = username)
            newUser.Subpassword(password)
            newUser.save()
            loginUser(request,newUser)
            messages.success(request,"Kayıt Başarılı")
            messages.warning(request,"DANGER")
            return render(request,"index.html")
           
        context ={
            "form":form
        }
        return render(request,"register.html",context)
       
    else:
        form = forms.SubUserForm()
        context ={
            "form":form
        }
        return render(request,"register.html",context)
```

Models:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class SubUser(models.Model):
    Subusername = models.CharField(max_length=15,verbose_name="kullanıcı adı")
    Subpassword = models.CharField(max_length=15,verbose_name="Parola")
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    Company = models.ForeignKey("auth.User", on_delete= models.CASCADE,verbose_name="Çalıştığı Firma")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Subusername
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you get the error at

```
newUser.Subpassword(password)
```

Should be

```
newUser.Subpassword=password
```